# restify auditLogger plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify, bunyan

I am using restify auditLogger plugin with bunyun logger.

```
server.on('after', restify.plugins.auditLogger({
    log: bunyan.createLogger({
      name: 'audit',
      stream: process.stdout
    }),
    event: 'after',
    printLog: true
  }));
```

but when I use an api for getting and posting things .. this code doesn't log anything in console of node. 
am I doing this right? or how to use bunyun logger with restify auditLogger ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where and for what type of server in nodejs is "after" an event?

Comment: @gforce301 in restify js .. see  http://restify.com/docs/plugins-api/#auditlogger